# Wrong label indexing in subfigures due to \ContinuedFloat

Tags: page-breaking, subfloats, subcaption, subfig

I'm having problems to create Figures with multiple subfigures.
I need to split one Figure into 2 pages, keeping one caption (Figure 1) and multiple subcaptions ((a), (b), (c), etc). I'm using `\ContinuedFloat` to do so. The code I have is working fine for one Figure.

However, if I try to use the same code to add more Figures, the lettering ((a), (b), (c), etc) gets wrong. Instead of Figure 2 starting with (a), it starts from the last letter of the previous Figure

Here is the code I'm using

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfigure[]{
    \includegraphics[width=50mm, height=29mm]{images/img3.png}
    \label{img3}
    }
    \subfigure[]{
    \includegraphics[width=50mm, height=29mm]{images/img4.png}
    \label{img4}
    }
\end{figure}
\clearpage
\begin{figure}[ht]\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfigure[]{
        \includegraphics[width=50mm, height=29mm]{images/img5.png}
        \label{img5}
        }
\caption{(a) blah (b) blah (c) blah}
    \label{AP}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As I said, if I use this code to create Figure 1, it works fine. However, if I use the same code to create Figure 2, the lettering gets wrong. Figure 2 starts with (d) instead of (a).

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: please always provide a small but complete test document (you can use `example-image` as the image.  If I try to make a document using the packages you state I get the errors `! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation (subcaption)                with the subfigure package.` and  `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \`H'.`

Comment: Hi David, sorry about that. I'm new here. I edit the question and I hope it is better now. I actually changed the question a bit. I realised that my problem might be with \ContinuedFloat. Would you know how to help?

Comment: Your example does not compile. Generally never use the `H` specicier.

Comment: Additionally please read the `subcaption` manual, `subfigure` is an environment not a macro, plus that env takes a mandatory width argument.

Comment: You have provided a test document but it generates the error `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \`H'.` and if you choose to scroll past that `! Missing number, treated as zero.`  You need to fix all errors before looking at the pdf file, the generated output is not intended to be usable after an error.